# Docker -Pika BlockingConnection Error

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq, pika

I have a docker container which runs a python script.The script is provided with an AMQP url which Pika uses as a pika.URLParameters for a BlockingConnection.When i run the script on my computer it worked fine.Since i dockerized it and monitored the logs of the container,i saw that the script jangs when the connection is attempted.Here is the code i use in the script:

```
AMQP_URL = __prefix__ + __username__ + ":" + __password__ + __virtual__host + session
("The programm hangs here")
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.URLParameters(AMQP_URL))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(
                          exchange = "tmp.topic_2",
                          exchange_type = "topic"
                        )

result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive = True)

queue_name = result.method.queue

channel.queue_bind(
                    exchange = "amq.topic",
                    queue = queue_name,
                    routing_key = "ui.#"
                  )
channel.basic_consume(
                      UiCallback,
                      queue= queue_name,
                      no_ack=True
                     )
channel.start_consuming()
```

I have included pika in the requirements.I wonder what the problem is:
Maybe the container can't access the web? Maybe i need to set up a rabbitmq server in this or another container?
Thank you for your help

Comment: ping `__virtual__host` from docker to start with.

Comment: Also, wait +2 minutes to see if timeout is triggered.

Comment: I try: `ping {virtual host}` both on my laptop and from inside the container,but i get: cannot resolve {virtual_host},unknown host.Still the script works on my laptop...

Comment: you need to setup DNS on the container then. in fact you should ping a real hostname or IP address, not {virtual host} literally.

Comment: I used: `ping google.com` and it worked inside the container.It seems that the container has access to the web.

Comment: Cool, now make sure to ping the value stored in __virtual__host variable.

Comment: I tried what you said and i keep getting: `unknown host`

Comment: So, a DNS problem. Probably it's a private network IP like 192.168.x.x, 172.16.xx or 10.x.x.x. Try to set container's DNS to the same servers as your laptop.

Comment: you should also post your dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment variable RABBIT_HOST_IP to the IP of the 'host' that your docker container is running on.

My understanding is that the blocking connection sends values back to the machine calling it which works fine but if you are inside a container the messages sent back are sent to the IP of the docker container which is not accessible off the machine.